# What is the Visual Basic (VB) equivalent of \ in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, special-characters

In C# you can use \ to ignore the special characters:

```
string myString = "this is a \" string";
```

that would work as one complete string... in VB, doing that does not work...

Anyone know the equivalent of \ to ignore special characters for VB?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VB.NET doubles up the quotes like this:

```
Dim myString As String = "this is a "" string"
```

Answer (score 4):

For the quotation, double the quote:

```
"This is a ""quote"""
```

For everything else, you're out of luck and have to resort to Chr

```
"This is a string with a " & Chr(10) & "line-feed"
```

Comment: Wow.  What on earth was the thinking behind this?

Comment: that's not true... you can use `vbCrLf`

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars_members.aspx for a list of all available control characters in VB.

Comment: The thinking is fairly obvious - when escape sequences exist, a person who's not aware of them will get confusing results if he writes a string literal that inadvertently includes one. This typically happens with path - how many questions can you remember about C# when people write "C:\foo.txt", and then complain about getting FileNotFoundException when it's clearly there etc... VB approach may be more verbose, but it's definitely more newbie-friendly. And it's consistent with traditional BASIC syntax, which never had escape sequences in string literals.

Comment: System.Environment.Newline can be useful in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex.Unescape` for using the c# style [escape sequences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88415.aspx) if you want to use it for other special characters besides the double quotes. To escape the double quotes use the (already mentioned) `""` ("double double quotes").

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape("Test\tTest"))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(Regex.Unescape("{0}:\t {1}"), a, x))
```

Ciao!
   Stefan

Comment: I am not sure how this directly answers the question asked. I can see it's sort of related, but all the OP needed was to know to use double-double-quotes.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: He asked for the escape character in c#. This character can be used to escape the double quote, but also to escape other special characters in C# (ok it won't work for double quote in VB). Maybe he only wants to know it for the double quote, but he didn't mention that...

Comment: I guess so; but considering the answer he accepted, I think he did mean the double quotes.