# Visual Basic 2010 String Containing a Speech Mark

Tags: vb.net

How can I make a speech mark in a string? The following shows the whole of the line and all code after that (With the Express IDE) to be a comment as well:

```
Variable = "\""
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Visual Basic (VB) equivalent of \ in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274079/what-is-the-visual-basic-vb-equivalent-of-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Variable = """"
```

Comment: its basically a bit like everything is a literal string @"""" in c# = """" in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Chr(34) or Convert.ToChar(34)